# Animate layout transition from Row to Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a row that by tapping on it, layout changes to the new one. I want to animate this layout transition. something you have seen a lot with hero animations. but hero is only for route transitions.

The target animation is very simple consist of size and position animations:

1. Image sizes increase and positioned to left: 0 , top: 0, right:
   screenSize.width and height to for example 200.
2. texts will move
   below the image
3. description text will enlarge enough to fit all
   remaining texts.

the problem is initial parent widget is `Row` but final parent widget is `Column`. but how can I animate this `Row` to `Column` layout transition? all the flutter animation tutorials I have seen relates to changing size, opacity, transform animations, but none of them described this kind of transition. How can I achieve this below layout transition animation?

[image]

Comment: You try use ``AnimatedContainer``?

Comment: It’s not possible, I can only animate container properties not children positions

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `AnimatedSwitcher`

> The AnimatedSwitcher widget allows you to switch between two or more widgets with an animation as you transition. By default, a FadeTransiton will appear between two widgets. Set a duration and play with the parameters to achieve the transition you are looking for.

Take a look at: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html

A demo:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2W7POjFb88g

Comment: I have tried. It doesn’t work, it just animated between two child, but doesn’t help to animate children from row to column